# Reference for computation of $K_8(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-k-theory

In an Oberwolfach report from 2016 [1, page 2] it is said that $K_8(\mathbb{Z})$ has recently been computed. Does anyone know a reference for the computation?

[1] https://orbilu.uni.lu/bitstream/10993/29499/1/preliminary_OWR_2016_52.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two preprints available:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.11598

https://www.utsc.utoronto.ca/people/kupers/wp-content/uploads/sites/50/2021/01/k8zshorter.pdf